# Stainless Steel Scrubber in Boil Screen to strain hops?

Tags: hops, filtering, boil-kettle

So I have a 6" boil screen in my kettle attached to my ball valve.

Now this doesn't strain that much hops out because of the larger holes in the screen so when I transfer it to my carboy I run it through a big funnel that has a screen in it to help filter. That screen constantly gets clogged and I have to sit there with a sanitized spoon and keep the screen clear.

So I was thinking to help strain more hops out of the kettle that I would put a stainless steel scrubber inside of the boil screen.

The good stainless steel ones say they won't rust, so would there be any other issue to using this?

These are the type of scrub pads I was looking at and here is the boil screen I have. I would put one inside of the screen and run the wort out of the kettle through it.

http://www.midwestsupplies.com/6-boil-screen.html

[http://www.amazon.com/Company-41496-Chore-Stainless-Scouring/dp/B000V74DJG](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000V74DJG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work. I've used a stainless scrubby to build a hopback, where the main point was to filter out the hops, keeping them in the container.

You may want to experiment with putting the scrubby around the braid rather than inside it, since it may be too tightly packed if put inside, preventing flow.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use a rather large funnel with removable screen which clogged so quickly I gave up on it. And my boil kettle has a bazooka screen which can still clog if I'm brewing something with a lot of hops. On at least one occasions I decided to throw caution to the wind, and just dumped it all into the fermenter, figuring I could rack it off the hops/trub later on anyway.

But you just reminded me of a couple alternatives, one being the brew-in-a-bag idea (repurposed here for the hops only), the other being this cheap-but-clever homemade hop bag device: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_7UBYqsOF0

Which reminds me, I still need to make one of those.